# Java BufferedReader miss some values

Tags: java, bufferedreader, named-pipes

I have problem with BufferedReader.

My source code works fine, but the problem is when I read a value from named pipe it missed some values.

```
delim="\t";
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/base.pip"));
while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
            try{
             timestamp = Long.parseLong(line.split(delim)[0]);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                continue;
            }
```

I need to read whole line to get first column value properly.

### example

original line : 12345678 A B

readed line: 2345678 A B     (missed first bit)

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem?

p.s it works fine, but only a few lines have problem like the above examples.

Comment: show us your `delim` please

Comment: What is delimiter you are using?

Comment: `delim='\t'`
thank you for your help

Comment: It won't skip the data. Print line after reading it. Problem with your delimiter

Comment: Then should I change my delimiter? Is there any other solution with using delim='\t'?

Comment: Update your question with the sample input and the actual code which assigns the delimiter.

Comment: What exception was thrown?

Comment: print the line before split and each element after split, after that check read data is correct or not. If the code as you shown so I think problem come from input data.

Comment: Note: the correct answer to 'what exception was thrown' is 'I don't know', because your catch block isn't telling you. So fix that and *then* tell us what exception was thrown. While you're at it, tell us whether the timestamp has the correct value for the line. And tell us what is your evidence that the data was written to the other end of the pipe as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your program and it works fine on my computer.

1. Check your delim `String delim = "\t"`
2. Check your file and it has a `tab` seperator between them.
3. Check the `line` value in your program.

If you don't have a tab space, consider using a regular expression which accepts any number of spaces.

```
String delim = "\\s+";
```

---

*`delim = '\t'`*

Split cannot take a character as a delimiter. Please check that. It has to be `delim = "\t"`

Comment: @EJP From the comments.

Comment: @Chloe what was the issue?

Comment: @Uma Kanth I guess my input was wrong. I send a 500 record per second to my pipe. That makes my input messy. I slowed down my send rate, and delim. Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Try to split it with Whitspaces and take the first out ouf the array like:

```
delim = "\\s";
timestamp = Long.parseLong(line.split(delim)[0]);
```

I think this should solve your problem.